# Need to hide parent element of inner element by using Closest

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Need to hide parent  element of inner element with name attribute by using closest as shown

```
<tr>
        
<td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113px" class="ms-formlabel">
<span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader">
<a name="SPBookmark_PatientInitials"></a>Patient Initials</span></td>
        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
        
            WR
                
            
        </td>
    </tr>
```

example is as below

```
.closest("tr> td span a ").attr('name', 'SPBookmark_' + ctx.ListSchema.Field[0].Name).hide();
```

Comment: what is the inner element and its parent in the example you provided?

Comment: You probably want `.closest("tr").find("td span a")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand what you are asking for, you can use the CSS attribute selector to achieve your goal (thanks to Scott for pointing out this is CSS not jQuery in the comments). Take this example:

```js
$("#hideParent").click(function(){
  $(".inner[name='foo']").closest('.outer').hide()
})
$("#showParent").click(function(){
  $(".inner[name='foo']").closest('.outer').show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner' name='foo'>
  Sample
  </div>
</div>

<button id="hideParent">Hide Parent</button>
<button id="showParent">Show Parent</button>
```

See the docs for more info: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: The attribute selector is not JQuery. It's a CSS selector. Also, because the OP has shown us their structure, your answer should use that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I was unsure what elements the OP was classifying as the parent element and inner element. My assumption would be to hide the `tr` based on the `a` but their example shows the selector for the `a` being hidden not the `tr`. I decided to make it general so they can apply it in any fashion they choose.

Answer (score 0):

[`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) should be called on the inner element and be supplied a valid CSS selector that should match some ancestor element. Your code:

```
.closest("tr> td span a ")
```

looks like it's trying to find what your code has as the inner element by starting at the ancestor and working downward..

```js
// Assuming that the <a> element is the current node...
let current = document.querySelector("a[name='SPBookmark_PatientInitials']");
current.closest("tr").classList.add("hidden");
```

```css
.hidden {display:none;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td nowrap="true" valign="top" width="113" class="ms-formlabel">
    <span class="ms-h3 ms-standardheader">
      <a name="SPBookmark_PatientInitials"></a>Patient Initials
    </span>
  </td>
  <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="350px" id="SPFieldText">
    WR
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```